# Merge points at a certain zoom level

Tags: cartography, arcgis-pro

On this website http://www.gisday.com/, if you scroll down a little bit, it shows a map of locations where GIS workshops are being held.

As you zoom in (or out), the number of points changes and they snap away from each other to their more appropriate location.

I looked around and thought the Integrate tool did that, but I was incorrect.

Does anyone know of a tool(s) in ArcGIS Pro that I can achieve that, or can provide insights?

Comment: Oops, my answer is for the javascript api which is what I was assuming you were looking for given the example. Sorry, I don't know a solution for Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cluster layer is right here, https://github.com/Esri/cluster-layer-js
or a more robust one here, https://github.com/odoe/esri-clusterfeaturelayer

Comment: Thanks for that I will look into it. I came across this article as well but no information on how to do it http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/06/10/100000-points-to-nowhere-cluster-points-to-streamline-maps/ . I tried looking into [Cluster and Outlier Analysis](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/cluster-and-outlier-analysis-anselin-local-moran-s.htm) there has to be a tool implemented into ArcGIS, at least I'm hoping there is. Reason is I'm trying to do it in the desktop version if possible rather than ArcGIS Online.

Comment: Yes, that article is confusing. Once again the endless supply of products gets everyone confused including all the people who commented on that article. The article is tagged ESRI Maps for IBM Cognos, ESRI Maps for MicroStrategy, so must not be for Pro. Good luck.